# Url is not being read from appsettings.json

Tags: c#, .net-core, config

Apologies in advance if I ask anything silly as this is all very new to me, but i essentially need to store a couple of hardcoded URLs that are living in the cs files into a json file.

This is not a web project, this project runs a series of selenium automation tests through NUNit its a .NETCore app

so My appsettings.json looks like:

```
{
  "Development": {
    "urlName": "https://dev.website.com"
  }
}
```

My Program.cs file looks like

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;


namespace Automation
{
    class Program
    {
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
            {
                config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
                config.AddCommandLine(args);               
            });
        
    }
}
```

Im basically creating a constructor in my startup "BaseTest" class, this is the class that gets run first before the test itself is executed the constructor is as follows:

```
  protected IConfiguration _config;

        public BaseTest()
        {
             _config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();
            baseUrl = _config["urlName"];
        }
```

the idea is that once this line in the BaseTest class is ran, it pulls the URL from the json file

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseUrl);
```

but its coming back as null, I know im missing something but idk what, or if im even in the right direction please help.

the appsettings.json file is also set to copy always

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`urlName` is in a property/section named `Development`

```
var baseUrl = _config.GetSection("Development")["urlName"]
```

<sub>***Note** : There are many other ways to do this in a typed manner, plumb it into .net core, integrate it more succinctly with DI and optionally using `IOptions`, however this is inline with what you had*</sub>

---

If you had [`Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder/) nuget installed you could also conceivably do something like this

```
public class Development
{
   public Uri UrlName { get; set; }
}

...

var myConfig = _config.GetSection(nameof(Development)).Get<Development>();
```

---

If you wanted to use the options pattern *one* of **many** ways, add the [`Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions/) nuget and do the following

```
services.Configure<Development>(_config.GetSection(nameof(Development)));
```